# Adding text to a div causes div to move down in it's parent container making a gap

Tags: html, css

EDIT 2016/04/19:

This is the site: http://gbgteambuilder.byethost7.com/

ORIGINAL:

I have a simple site which has some table elements (in `#playerTable`), that when clicked their containing text is added as an `<h3>` element to the `#playerPool` div to the table's left.  When the text is added though, the `#playerPool` appears to move down about a centimeter, exposing the background color of the containing div, `#interfaceContainer`.

What I've been trying to achieve is to have two divs alongside each other, `#playerPoolContainer` and `#playerRoster` that take up the entire height of `#interfaceContainer`.  Right now they have differing heights, the `#playerRoster` only goes down about 2/3 the way as far as `#playerPool` container.  That, and this weird behavior when an `<h3>` tag is added, I'm unsure what is causing this.

```css
 body,
 html {
   height: 100%;
 }
 div.main {
   height: 100%;
 }
 body {} #interfaceContainer {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: green;
 }
 #playerPoolContainer {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 55%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #playerPool {
   position: relative;
   background: blue;
   width: 100%;
   height: fill;
   float: top;
 }
 #playerRoster {
   vertical-align: top;
   background: black;
   overflow: auto;
   padding: 8px;
   color: white;
 }
 #playerRoster form {
   float: right;
 }
 #playerRoster input,
 #playerRoster p,
 #playerRoster button {
   margin: 4px;
 }
 #output {
   float: top;
   height: 240px;
   background: black;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .player {
   background: black;
   color: white;
   width: auto;
 }
 #playerTable {
   width: 100%;
   border: 1;
   table-layout: fixed;
 }
 #playerTable td {
   width: 25%;
 }
 .selectedPlayer {
   background: yellow;
   color: black;
 }
 h3 {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="resources/MochiKit/Base.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/MochiKit/Iter.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/MochiKit/DOM.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/MochiKit/Style.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>

  <script src="js/dbhelper.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/utility.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <style>
    a.test {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="interfaceContainer">
    <div class="main" id="playerPoolContainer">
      <div id="output">
      </div>
      <div class="main" id="playerPool">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" id="playerRoster">
      <form id=addPlayerForm action="server/db/dbInsert.php" method="get">
        <p>Add new player:</p>
        <input id="addPlayerInput" name="data" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitPlayer">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your stylesheet and its working.

```
body,
 html {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
 }
 div.main {
   height: 100%;
 }
 body {} #interfaceContainer {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: green;
   margin: 0px;
 }
 #playerPoolContainer {
   position: fixed;
   float: left;
   width: 55%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #playerPool {
   position: relative;
   background: blue;
   width: 100%;
   height: calc(100%-240px);
   display: block;
   float: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   margin: 0px;
 }
 #playerRoster {
   float: none;  
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 0px;
   background: black;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0px;
   color: white;
   width: calc(100%-55%);
   height: 100%;
   //display: block;
 }
 #playerRoster form {
   float: right;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
 }
 #playerRoster input,
 #playerRoster p,
 #playerRoster button {
   margin: 4px;
 }
 #output {
   float: top;
   height: 240px;
   background: black;
   bottom: 0;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0px;
 }
 .player {
   background: black;
   color: white;
   width: auto;
 }
 #playerTable {
   width: 100%;
   border: 1;
   table-layout: fixed;
 }
 #playerTable td {
   width: 25%;
 }
 .selectedPlayer {
   background: yellow;
   color: black;
 }
 h3 {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

You can see the demo [here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vapxnyoj/)

Comment: It didn't work.  I added the site to my question if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: I don't understand. Its working fine on my pc. Have you tried the jsfiddle  link I provided? Please provide a jsfiddle link to your site so I can edit it.

Comment: You know you can edit code on the actual page, right? (at least in chrome)

Comment: If you use the css in your solution, it does fix the heights and the div moving, but now the `#playerRoster` is somehow behind the `#playerPool` and when it gets populated with the player table, the table is hidden except for the end of its right side.

Comment: I tried but not able to edit your code in chrome. Can you provide all the components of your site including that table in different colors. It is difficult to work in black and blue without any data.